# Can't set currentTime in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html5-audio

For some reason in Chrome I can't set the currentTime property of the audio tag. I can alert the currentTime and it displays correctly but when I try to set the currentTime it reverts to zero. There is an event listener on a progress bar which triggers the alert shown below. It always displays as zero. In FireFox and IE the alert works just fine. What's the problem with Chrome?

```
$(document).ready(function(){document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener(
                                    'click',
                                    function(e) {

             document.getElementById("audio_id_1").currentTime = 10;
             alert(document.getElementById("audio_id_1").currentTime);
             ...
             ...

<audio id="audio_id_1" preload="metadata">
    <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Comment: where is var currentAudioId defined?

Comment: what are ```progressbar``` and ```currentAudioId```. Please paste the code below for more insight other no one will be able to assist you. Probably looking at this partial script, the fix should be ```alert(document.getElementById('audio_id_1').currentTime);``` because you are referencing ```currentAudioId``` which isn't declared/initialized yet.

Comment: So if I do alert(document.getElementById("audio_id_1").currentTime); the time displays. This is Only in Chrome... what is it about Chrome that I can't set currentTime to something new. The progressBar is defined like so: <progress id="progressBar" value="0.0" max="1"></progress>

Comment: If I change the audio src to this clip I found it works as expected...   src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3". I don't know why I can set the currentTime for this clip in Chrome but not my own test.mp3 ??? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

My chrome can seek "local" audios and videos well, whose source urls start wich "blob:"

So I solved this in such the redundant way:

- download the whole media (XMLHttpRequest);
- *get the blob url (URL.createObjectURL);*
- change the source url of the media

```js
    function makeChromeSeekable(){ 
        var player = document.getElementById("thevideo")                                                                                                                                                                          
        var uReader = new XMLHttpRequest()                                                                                                                                                             
        uReader.open ('GET', player.src, true)                                                                                                                                                        
        uReader.responseType = 'blob'                                                                                                                                      
        uReader.onload = () => {                                                                                                                                                                           
            player.src = URL.createObjectURL(uReader.response)                                                                                                                                                        
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        uReader.send()                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }    
    makeChromeSeekable()
```

PS: The video files mignt be too large for downloading, but audio files should always be feasible.

PS. I used to believe that blob data has to be converted as data(File.getDataURL), but now using blob urls is ok seems more convenient.