# Audio and video set current Time is not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, html5-audio

I don't know why setting audio current time is not working on google chrome while it's working fine on other browsers.

Here is my code.

```
<template>
<div>
    <audio ref="audioRef" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
    <div style="width: 280px !important">
        <div class="my-1 px-0 mx-0">
            <v-slider
                dense
                height="15"
                @change="moveAudio"
                hide-details
                :value="playerProgress"
            ></v-slider>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            playerProgress: 0,
        };
    },

    methods() {
        playPauseAudio() {
            const audio = this.$refs.audioRef;         
            audio.paused ? audio.play(); : audio.pause();           
        },
        moveAudio(value) {
            const audio = this.$refs.audioRef;
            this.playerProgress = value;
            audio.currentTime = value; // This part cause audio to restart in google chrome while in other browsers it's going to that time.
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add more code snippet and details so it will be easy to help you out.

Comment: restarts audio ? probably because `value` is negative or above duration of audio.

Comment: No actually I have handled that part. No negative value or above duration is passed. It just restarts on chrome. It's working perfect on other browsers as I mentioned.

Comment: I can confirm exactly the same issue here :(.

Comment: And at least in my case it looks to be a "feature" related to how a file is served: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804889/1642887 - which is sadly not a thing I can alter.

Comment: I recently figured out that it’s only not working due to CORS policy. In my case I was accessing audio from ‘http://localhost:3000’ while my server was on ‘http://localhost:8000’ and bcoz both are http not https it was causing that problem. Its was fixed automatically when I host my project on live server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't set currentTime in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293767/cant-set-currenttime-in-chrome)